# How to insert product to shopping cart then register or login

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have product , orderdetails and customer tables 

 the orderdetails table have  `products_id (FK)` `customers_id(FK)`  `Quantity` and `size` when customer is logged in and add items the items are inserted in the orderdetails table  I want to allow the customer to add items/products to cart even without login then they can either login or register 

 Do I need another table for that ?

Database 
`productTable (products_id(pk), products_name , price,Quantity ,size )` 
`customerTable (customers_id(pk), cust_name, cust_email )` 
`orderdetails (products_id(FK), customers_id(FK), price,Quantity,size  )`

```
     <?php
include'config.php'; 
  session_start();  

if(isset($_SESSION['product_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['product_name'])) {
 $products_name =$_SESSION['product_name'];
 }
if(isset($_SESSION['products_price']) && !empty($_SESSION['products_price'])) {
 $products_price =$_SESSION['products_price'];
}


 if(isset($_SESSION['Quantity']) && !empty($_SESSION['Quantity'])) {
  $Quantity = $_SESSION['Quantity'];

 } 
  if(isset($_SESSION['product_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['product_id'])) {
  $product_id =   $_SESSION['product_id'];
 }
   if(isset($_SESSION['customers_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['customers_id'])) {
         $customers_id =   $_SESSION['customers_id'];

   } 
    if(isset($_SESSION['size']) && !empty($_SESSION['size'])) {
       $size =   $_SESSION['size'];

   } 
 $query = "INSERT INTO orderdetails  (products_id,customers_id,price,Quantity ,size) VALUES ('$product_id','$customers_id','$products_price','$Quantity','$size')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query) ;
    mysqli_close($conn);




?>
```

Comment: No. You don't need another table for that. I believe this has something to do with how you add the items in your code. Try posting that code so people here can have better understanding of your problem.

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin should I post code of my sql insert or table info?

Comment: Your PHP code, SQL query, and anything that is relevant with adding items to cart. That way, people could better understand your problem instead of making guesses. That way, they point you to specific and relevant steps you need to make.

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin I updated with the code

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. If customers_id is not a foreign key or part of, you could simply generate a new customer_id for each user not logged in and use this one. As soon as the user then logs in, you'd update the table:

```sql
UPDATE orderdetails SET customers_id = <id of user logged in>
    WHERE customers_id = <previous temporary id>
```

If the session expires, you would delete any entries again (a shopping cart of a user not logged in cannot survive expired sessions, of course):

```sql
DELETE FROM orderdetails WHERE customers_id = <temporary id>
```

If customers_id *is* a foreign key, you need to additionally create a temporary customer entry as soon as the first item is added to the shopping car. Then, when the session expires, delete this entry, too. And you need to delete the temporary entry, as soon as a registered user logs in, together with the update of customer_id in orderdetails.

Comment: do you mean I should create temporary customer id in customer table ? or orderdetails

Comment: Going with what Aconcagua suggested and your code above, you should create a temporary customer ID in the customer table and use that ID when you're adding items to order details table.

Comment: The temporary user entry in customer table is actually only *necessary* if customer_id in orderdetails is a foreign key. You could create one by default, of course. This can help, if you want to find these temporary shopping cars in other queries (which use joins on customer and orderdetails), too. Otherwise (no foreign key *and* not wanted to find in joins), you can simply store this temporary id in the user's *session*, get the cart via `SELECT * FROM orderdetails WHERE id = <stored id>` and omit the temporary user. Depends on your requirements.